# find lines from a file with the content of another file Python

Tags: python

So.. here's what i'm trying to do..
For each line in the datafile, check if the other file contains this string.

I tried some stuff from other posts, but non of them were any good.

The code below says it didnt find any of the string it was looking for, even while they were present somewhere in the file.

```
def search():
    file1= open('/home/example/file1.txt', 'r')
    datafile= open('/home/user/datafile.txt', 'r')

    for line in datafile:
        if line in file1:
            print '%s found' % line
        else:
            print '%s not found' % line

search()
```

Comment: are you trying to find identical lines in both files?

Comment: You need to add a `.read()` to the file opens, or you can add it after you open the file in the for loop.

Comment: .read() works, but only if the line is identical.
If it has to search for "hello", it wont be able to find it if it's written as "hello123".

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the content of the first file is not extremely large, you can read the entire file as string and then check using string containment:

```
def search():
    file1_content = open('/home/example/file1.txt').read()
    datafile = open('/home/user/datafile.txt')

    for line in datafile:
        if line in file1_content:
            print '%s found' % line
        else:
            print '%s not found' % line
```

Note that the default mode for `open` is `'r'`, so you really don't need to pass that parameter if you're reading in text mode.

Comment: You also forgot a read in the "datafile" opening, either add it in the for loop, so `for line in datafile.read()` or when you open the file.

Comment: @PrestonHager That will not be entirely necessary. The lines will be equally fetched without calling `read`. And note that once you use `read`, you can't implicitly iterate over lines except you again call `splitlines`

Comment: Ok, I didn't test the code so I can't say for sure. But I'm pretty sure you have to call a read or something with a `.split('\n')`. Not saying you're wrong but I'm don't think your right.

Comment: You can add .readlines() instead of read and it will iterate on the list with each line. No need to split

Comment: @chuseuiti That will not be necessary. Each line will be produced by iterating on the file object, similar to `readlines`, but without the extra method call

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a `set` and then check for inclusion in the second file. `set`'s are typically faster at checking inclusion that lists.

```
def search():
    file1 = set(open('/home/example/file1.txt'))
    datafile= open('/home/user/datafile.txt', 'r')

    for line in datafile:
        if line in file1:
            print '%s found' % line
        else:
            print '%s not found' % line
```

You could also use set operations to extract, for instance, all lines not in the first file:

```
set(open('/home/user/datafile.txt', 'r')) - set(open('/home/example/file1.txt'))
```